# How is WordPress redirecting/rewriting my URL?

Tags: wp-redirect

i'm running a wordpress free classified website and the address is http://www.gosell.co.uk what i need is if a user from london open this url then it should be concatenated with http://www.gosell.co.uk/london or london.gosell.co.uk is that possible? shall i make a new function or wat? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [wordpress maxmind plug-in](http://www.jonlee.ca/jons-geolocation-plugin/). I've never used it myself, but it should do the heavy lifting of identifying a user's location by IP address.

You'll have to add some functions to dictate what to do with that data in terms of redirecting visitors (the plug-in only figures out where they are). You'll probably also need to add bits to handle situations when the location isn't recognized (or isn't in the UK, for example).